# In Odoo how to force overwriting of a record rule which is defined in a base module and data is set to noupdate='1'?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

The following record rule is defined in *product* module

```xml
<data noupdate="1">
    <record id="product_comp_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name" >Product multi-company</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_product_template"/>
        <field name="global" eval="True"/>
        <field name="domain_force"> ['|',('company_id','=',user.company_id.id),('company_id','=',False)]</field>
    </record>
</data>
```

I want to edit it in my custom module to be

```xml
<record id="product.product_comp_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name" >All Products (Parent Company)</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="product.model_product_template"/>
    <field name="global" eval="True"/>
    <field name="domain_force">['|','|',('company_id','=',user.company_id.id),('company_id','=','False'),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id])] </field>
</record>
```

Comment: why does this question get minus flag?
i have the some problem, does anyone get the answer yet?

Answer (score 10):

You can use :

```xml
<function name="fix_er_role" model="ir.rule"/>
```

After that add the method to ir.rule and fix your data

```py
class IRRule(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.rule'
    
    def fix_er_role(self):
         rol_id = self.env.ref('product.product_comp_rule')
         rol_id = self.env['ir.rule'].search([('id','=',rol_id)])
         rol_id.write({'domain_force':['|','|',('company_id','=',user.company_id.id),('company_id','=','False'),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id])]})
```

**Edit** : an other good solution for this requirement.

```xml
    <function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
         <!-- get the record if from data base -->
        <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
            <value
              eval="[('module', '=', 'product'), ('name', '=', 'product_comp_rule')]"
              />
        </function>
       <!-- remove noupdate -->
        <value eval="{'noupdate': False}" />
    </function>


    <record id="product.product_comp_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name" >All Products (Parent Company)</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="product.model_product_template"/>
        <field name="global" eval="True"/>
        <field name="domain_force">['|','|',('company_id','=',user.company_id.id),('company_id','=','False'),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id])] </field>
    </record>

    <!-- reset noupdate -->
    <function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
        <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
            <value
              eval="[('module', '=', 'product'), ('name', '=', 'product_comp_rule')]"
              />
        </function>
        <value eval="{'noupdate': True}" />
    </function>
```

Comment: it seems obsolete in odoo v16, as i get Error:     raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /home/odoo/src/user/mail_template_zsb/data/mail_template_def.xml:3, somewhere inside
<function model="mail.template" name="replace_in_body_html" eval="[]"/>

Answer (score 4):

In Odoo 13 the XML solution worked just without the comments

```xml
    <function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
        <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
            <value eval="[('module', '=', 'product'), ('name', '=', 'product_comp_rule')]"/>
        </function>
        <value eval="{'noupdate': False}" />
    </function>

    <record id="product.product_comp_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name" >All Products (Parent Company)</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="product.model_product_template"/>
        <field name="global" eval="True"/>
        <field name="domain_force">['|','|',('company_id','=',user.company_id.id),('company_id','=','False'),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id])] </field>
    </record>

    <!-- reset noupdate -->
    <function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
        <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
            <value eval="[('module', '=', 'product'), ('name', '=', 'product_comp_rule')]"/>
        </function>
        <value eval="{'noupdate': True}" />
    </function>
```

The issue was already reported by someone else https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/45592

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in another sample way using *noupdate="0"*

```xml
<data noupdate="0">
    <record id="product.product_comp_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name" >All Products (Parent Company)</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="product.model_product_template"/>
        <field name="global" eval="True"/>
        <field name="domain_force">['|','|',('company_id','=',user.company_id.id),('company_id','=','False'),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id])] </field>
    </record>
</data>
```

Comment: The solution isn't working from odoo 8 onwards, hence you need first to disable the update for that specific record and write your changes, then preferably put back the noupdate =  True